# jQuery UI options versus methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

What is the semantic difference between jQuery UI widget options and methods?

Initialize slider widget with options object defining the value option.

```
$('#mySlider').slider({ value: 10});
```

Get value option.

```
var optValue = $('#mySlider').slider('option', 'value');
```

Get value.

```
var methodValue = $('#mySlider').slider('value');
```

Is it possible that optValue and methodValue can be different?

Comment: That all depends on how the plugin has been written. I suppose the answer is, the differences are, whatever the author of the plugin deemed the differences to be.

Comment: The slider api documentation does not make a distinction, but i can produce code which behaves differently depending on whether one uses a method or an option.

Comment: @Liam This would be suboptimal, no? Framework api's should provide clarity and consistency from a semantic standpoint.

Comment: You can always debug the Script yourself. It's not compiled. Bear in mind most (if not all) of these plugins are open source maintained by a team of poeple who don't get paid. Some have very good documentation, some don't. *"You pay's your money you's takes your chances"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, there is no *semantic* difference. `option` merely calls the underlying get/set.

*On widget methods*: When you call `$(element).widget("someMethod", parameters)` what happens is (for the purposes of the question) a call to `widgetPrototype.someMethod(parameters)`.

`widget.("option", property)` is a special case of widget method. As a getter, it goes straight to the underlying `options` object, but as a setter calls the `widget._setOptions()` function. From the documentation:

> option( options )
>
> Returns: jQuery (plugin only)
>
> Sets one or more options for the widget.
>
> options Type: Object A map of option-value pairs to set.

Here's a breakdown of what happens:

```
$('#mySlider').slider({ value: 10});
// call the slider widget's initialiser with parameter {value:10}

var optValue = $('#mySlider').slider('option', 'value');
// call the slider widget's .option() method with parameter value

var methodValue = $('#mySlider').slider('value');
// calls the slider widget's .value() method.
//
// EDIT: Yes, this CAN be different from .option(value)
// It falls on the implementer to document their widget well
// enough that users know what's going on
//
// Having said that, I have yet to see a popular jquery widget
// where .someWidgetOption() is not just a shortcut to .option("someWidgetOption")
```

The documentation is remarkably good: http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/